# Can/should new MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync work offline?

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

A throwaway phrase [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818495.aspx)<sup>1</sup> makes me think that my telephone should be able to use the downloaded maps to do a location lookup, even when offline.

But I don't seem to be able to get it to work when there's no internet connection. I get a result with State = Success, but the list of locations is empty.

I've wondered whether it might be the phone trying to check the AuthenticationToken, rather than the actual geo lookup...

Any thoughts?

<sup>1</sup>*"However, mapping services also work without Internet connectivity when maps are downloaded for offline use."*